# aws auto scaling with dynamic configuration

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

I have a usecase where there are multiple tasks I need to run which run using autoscaling group. and as the number of tasks grows high, a new ec2 instance is spawned up in the aws asg. But here different tasks have different resource requirement. Some can run in 2 GB of ram and some need 32 GB of Rams. I want spawn the new instance of appropriate configuration dynamically. How is that possible in aws?

Comment: Do you have different EC2 instances for different tasks? If yes, how about using two different auto scaling groups with same target group? It'll scale according to launch configuration applied to each autoscaling group.

Comment: Can you explain more about how the tasks run using an autoscaling group? From what I know, autoscaling groups are groups of EC2 instances.

Comment: Hi! just add the autoscaling policies based on the metrics from the ECS cluster. With this, first, scale the ECS service with ECS scale policies and the scale the ASG with the global ECS metrics.

Comment: So, basically. I am running a heavy Service which has a UI. when user hits the url. a new machine in asg opens to start that service and user see the UI. I am using asg for this because number of People using that UI could be  huge and different people can't share each other work. Each service should be completely different from each other hence running on asg through dockers. each time a new user comes a new machine and starts up running a new docker.